# Switch XIB's fading through Black?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

I am attempting to switch views (XIB's) while fading through black. I have been doing this using UIView animations and I want to keep it that way. The problem is that whenever I switch views I am not fading through black, its more of a fade directly to the next XIB.

How would I properly do this?

Here is my code *(self.view = view1.view in my case, but maybe I shouldn't do that)*:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                     animations:^{
                         [view1.view setAlpha:0];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.view.superview addSubview:view2.view];
                         [view2.view setAlpha:0];
                         [view2.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                                          animations:^{
                                              [view2.view setAlpha:1];  
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [view1.view removeFromSuperview];
                                          }];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the background color of self.view is *part* of that view. When you fade the view, it fades the background too.

Instead, you should put a view that you keep on the screen all the time, that's empty and has a black background color, and is behind view1 or view2.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the color of my UIWindow solve that issue? But its not really the color that is the issue but the actual animation for switch views. I explained that issue in my post.

Comment: I fiddled with the code a bit and it seems to work so thanks anyway!